# contactTestBitMask not detecting in didBeginContact (Logs) in SpriteKit with Swift

Tags: swift, xcode

I’m making a simple spriteKit game and I have all my physicsBodies set up. I have added  the proper categoryBitMasks and ContactTestBitMask to detect contact.

When I run the app I have contact but it does not show in the Logs for didBeginContact where I added print(“contact”)

I cant seem to get by this. I have looked over probably all the questions and tutorials most similar to this.

I have tried 2 different methods

```
enum ColliderType : UInt32 {
    case None   = 0
    case All    = 0xFFFFFFFF
    case enemy  = 0b001
    case hero   = 0b010
    case screen = 0b100
}
```

and

```
let heroCategory :UInt32   = 0x1 << 0
let screenCategory:UInt32  = 0x1 << 1
let enemyCategory:UInt32   = 0x1 << 2
let scoreCategory:UInt32   = 0x1 << 3
```

Its strange how I have contact but it doesn’t print in the logs.

I have a moving background, moving enemies coming towards the hero. The hero moves to dodge the enemies.

I tried adding a “gameOver” function to see if it will stop the game by setting

```
if self.movingParts.speed > 0 {
        self.movingParts.speed = 0
```

And setting the speed in touchesBegan function

I can upload the code if needed. Please let me know.

Any kind of help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after 17 days I finally figured it out a solution that really wasn't my fault.

All I did was erase

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    print("contact")
}
```

And RE-TYPED IT. Wow, strange but it worked. I have noticed this issue with other problems (re-typing the code for it to work).

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 things you need to set.

```
physicsBody.categoryBitMask
physicsBody.contactTestBitMask
physicsBody.collisionBitMask
```

Also be sure to set the SKPhysicsContactDelegate. You should have SKPhysicsContactDelegate after your class at the top

```
Class GameScene : SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
```

And be sure you have this in your didMoveToView

```
self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
```

Hope your this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have all the info you added. Like I mentioned, I run the app with no Errors or warnings.

Comment: Oh ok, I would need to see the code where you have 'print contact '